# Gradle Test, run verbosely?

Tags: java, testing, logging, command-line, gradle

We have a task in our Gradle build file called `integration` which extends Test and is used to run all of our integration tests.  Our integration tests take quite some time to run because we have, as you might expect, quite a few.  And several of them can run for up to 10 minutes because of some lengthy DB interactions.

Right now all I can see when they are running is `>Building > :integration`.  And it sits at that point for...a very long time.  I'm often not sure if it's just in the middle of a bunch of long tests, or if it's hanging on something it really shouldn't be hanging on.

So, I was wondering if there is a way to get them to run verbosely?  So I can see which test we are actually on?  I just want the command line to spit out something like:

```
Running test <testName>: Started...Complete (231 sec)
```

I've looked through the Gradle documentation and haven't seen anything that shows how this might be done.  Granted, I am a little new at this, so...  If anyone has an idea how this could be done?  I would prefer to have a flag that just does it, but if it can be done with some scripting I'm willing to learn.  Just point me in that direction...

Comment: See `Test#testLogging` in the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html) DSL doc. In general what You need is make use of `beforeTest` and `afterTest` closures. You can keep the invocation start in a global map.

```
def times = [:]

test {
   beforeTest { td ->
      times[td.name] = System.currentTimeMillis()
      println "$td.name started"
   }

   afterTest { td ->
      println "$td.name finished in ${System.currentTimeMillis() - times[td.name]}"
   }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is synchronous. You need to try.

Comment: If you want this output for only the integration tests, add these to the `integration` task instead of the `test` task.